# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Переформулирую вопрос. Видимо, с утра я воспринимала русский язык очень специфично. Разделяются ли запятой прилагательное с зависимым словом и следующее за ним причастие?

Возможна очистка методом пиггинг: выдавливание содержимого трубопровода посредством точно подогнанного (,) двигающегося рабочего тела.

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, пунктуационные справочники в разделах, касающихся разграничения однородных и неоднородных определений, отражают далеко не все встречающиеся способы их выражения и комбинации.
В предложении, которое Вы приводите, определения все-таки являются неоднородными, поэтому запятая между ними не нужна: "Возможна очистка методом пиггинг: выдавливание содержимого трубопровода посредством точно подогнанного  двигающегося рабочего тела". 
В этом предложении причастный оборот "плотно подогнанный" предшествует одиночному причастию "двигающийся". Одиночное препозитивное причастие сближается с прилагательным, и поэтому, как представляется, на этот случай можно распространить следующее правило: "если причастный оборот стоит перед определением-прилагательным и относится к следующему затем сочетанию определения-прилагательного и определяемого слова, то запятая между ними не ставится" (Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник. М., 2009. С. 198).

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, запятая не нужна. Определения неоднородные.

*...методом **пиггинга**: **выдавливания**... с помощью...*

Comment: Я тоже думаю, что не нужна.

Comment: Почему-то ответ Сержа пришел только ко мне на почту. Я все-таки склоняюсь здесь к запятой...

Comment: Аленка, я задал вопрос Грамме.ру и вот что они ответили. Мой ответ по неизвестным мне причинам удалился.